# Unable to Launch Chrome Browser in Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I am launching chrome browser using

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*googlechrome",
                    "https://example.com/");
```

But i get a popup with following message and it freezes:

> *An administrator has installed Google Chrome on this system, and it is available for all users. The system-level Google Chrome will replace your user-level installation now.*

Console Log till point of freeze:

```
Server started
16:06:37.792 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*googlechrome, https://example.com/, ] on session null
16:06:37.796 INFO - creating new remote session
16:06:38.081 INFO - Allocated session beb925cd0418412dbe6319fedfb28614 for https://example.com/, launching...
16:06:38.082 INFO - Launching Google Chrome...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try giving location of your chrome exe too along with browser name like this :

```
selenium=new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*googlechrome C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", "https://example.com");
```