# Chrome Driver exception at Start

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i'm having the following error:

> An administrator has installed Google Chrome on this system, and it is
>   available for all users. The system-level Google Chrome will replace
>   your user-level installation now.

When trying to run a test in chrome driver on windows 10. This happens when it starts to initialize the driver. Has anyone face this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This error occurs when Google Chrome is available for all users. By default, when Google Chrome installs it is installed in the AppData folder so it does not require admin rights for installation*.

Navigate to:

> C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome

Where you should find a folder called Application. Delete the folder and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling chrome from both the directories

```
c:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\
c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\
```

Also, if it doesn't work then try the below link.

[Unable to Launch Chrome Browser in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452637/unable-to-launch-chrome-browser-in-selenium)

Based on the above link, you can set the chrome binary as

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();  
options.setBinary("path\\to\\chrome.exe");
```

See the ChromeOptions documentation at:

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-Using-a-Chrome-executable-in-a-non-standard-location